# Alamofire API request is getting failed with responseSerializationFailed in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, web-services, alamofire

I am calling normal API call with Alamofire, And I am not passing any data with that in networking manager class.

My Networking class is

```
func executeGetRequest(url:String,requestVC:UIViewController,completionHandler:@escaping (_ responseObject:Any?) -> Void!,failureHandler:@escaping (_ connectionError:NSError?) -> Void!){

    //Checking internet alert
    if !self.isConnectedToInternet(){
        // requestVC.showAlert(kText_AppName, message: kText_NoInternet)
        return
    }

    requestVC.showLoader()
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON {
        (response:DataResponse) in

        requestVC.removeLoader()

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                completionHandler (response.result.value)
            }
            break

        case .failure(let error):
            failureHandler (error as NSError?)
            break

        }
    }
}
```

and i am calling it from my main class

```
kNetworkManager.executeGetRequest(url: kAppAccessTokenURL, requestVC: self, completionHandler: {
     (responseObject) -> () in
          print("responseObject:\(responseObject!)")


      }, failureHandler: {(error)-> () in
          print("response object:\(error!)")
          self.showAlert(message: (error?.description)!, title: kText_AppName)
          if error?._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                //timeout here
                self.showAlert(message: kText_timeout, title: kText_AppName)
           }
      })
```

Its getting always request fail and showing error as `responseSerializationFailed`

if I call directly in Main Class without manager class like

```
Alamofire.request(kAppAccessTokenURL).responseString { response in
```

I am able to getting response, can anyone suggest me where getting wrong in Network class.

Comment: `Alamofire.request(kAppAccessTokenURL).responseString ` works because you want your response to be a string. But when you ask `Alamofire` to serialize response into json i.e. calling `Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON` then it's failing because your response is not a JSON but some random string

Comment: So, how to fix this?

Comment: Check what are you getting in the `Alamofire.request(kAppAccessTokenURL).responseString` and tell your server guy that you're getting this response instead of a JSON

Comment: What is the response for the api? May be you get array of objects instead of a standard dictionary. Like @InderKumarRathore pointed using string would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you

```
Alamofire.request(kAppAccessTokenURL).responseString
```

and  there

```
 Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON
```

look to that

```
     let jsonText = "{\"first_name\":\"Sergey\"}"
        var dictonary:NSDictionary?

        if let data = jsonText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

            do {
                dictonary =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                if let myDictionary = dictonary
                {
                     print(" First name is: \(myDictionary["first_name"]!)")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am passing there url only @Uma Madhavi

Comment: @umaMadhavi if its json data how can we do it?

Comment: do I need to check in runtime?

Comment: @Uma Madhavi can you have look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919964/how-to-create-model-class-for-json-response-from-webservice-in-swift-3

Comment: replace responseJSON in network manager with responseString as it works then convert that to dictionary and parse it

Comment: @Sh_Khan Alamofire.request(kAppAccessTokenURL).responseString
this is working, if it string data, it will work, else if it json data, how to handle there?

Comment: why you have to handle it in json if the other way works

Comment: that means that the content from your server isn't json convertable

Comment: you can't acces implementation of almofire it parses your return to json and fails the only way is to handle the return from server

Comment: Any way I accepted your answer, can you look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919964/how-to-create-model-class-for-json-response-from-webservice-in-swift-3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161720/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-sh-khan).