# Alamofire - ResponseSerializationFailed while sending and Receiving JSON

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, alamofire

I've to send a JSON object to my API and receive response in JSON format.
Following is snapshot of working API in PostMan
[image]

But when I send request in Alamofire, I get **responseSerializationFailed** error. Below is the code.

```
self.url = URL(string: "http://xyzxyz/api/CheckQRCode")!

let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

let parameters: [String:Any] = [
            "QrCode": carIdentifier,
            "qrCodeImageDumy": strBase64
        ]
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Accept":"application/json"
        ]

Alamofire.request(self.url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let rawJson = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Received Malformed data from server")
                    return
                }
                let formattedJson = JSON(rawJson)

            case .failure(let error):
                errorBlock(error)
            }
        }
```

But I receive following error.
[image: in xcode]
Any kind help please !

Comment: change it to URLEncoding at the place of JSONEncoding

Comment: @V_rohit, no progress. Same

Comment: Are you getting the data in postman, your snapshot shows that you are getting null from api

Comment: That's correct data as per my use case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923953/alamofire-api-request-is-getting-failed-with-responseserializationfailed-in-swif check this maybe you could get help

Comment: or check your api also

Comment: post QrCode and qrCodeImage dummy values in your answer as simple text so that it can be tested. Currently it is an image